# How can I allow persisting without parent document with an embeds_many association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have 2 Mongoid models that look something like this:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String

  embeds_many :jobs
end

class Job
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :title, type: String

  embedded_in :user
end
```

This allows me to do something like

```
user.jobs.create(title: 'Test Job')
```

However, I'd like to be able to have some predefined jobs for a user to choose from, which would then be embedded in the user's document. Something like this:

```
Job.create(title: 'Predefined Job')
user.jobs << Job.first
```

However, creating a job on it's own throws the following error

> Cannot persist embedded document Role without a parent document.

I'm kind of new to Mongoid, and can't find any examples of this in the documentation. Anyone know how you would do this?

Comment: I'd probably have a `PredefinedJob` standalone document.

Comment: I go with a `PredefinedJob` class too

Answer (score 7):

> Cannot persist embedded document Role without a parent document.

As the error clearly states `embedded document` can only be embedded within another document. It cant exist as its own. If you wanted to make a Role independent from user, you need change the relation to `has_many` from `embeds_many`

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String

  has_many :jobs
end

class Job
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :title, type: String

  belongs_to :user
end
```

so you can

```
Job.create(title: 'Predefined Job')
user.jobs << Job.first
```

and

```
job = Job.new(title: 'Predefined Job')
job.save
```

or if you still wanted to go ahead with `embed_many` relation, you need to make a separate document to store the predefined jobs